# Convex hull of curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in \mathbb{R}[t]$ and let $S = \{(f_1(t), \ldots, f_n(t)) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Is there a method of computing the convex hull of this set? How about if each $f_i$ has the same degree?

In the case I'm interested in, each $f_i$ has degree $4$, and $n=5$.

From what I can tell, this involves some sort of algebraic geometry (involving semialgebraic sets, over the real numbers).

For what it's worth, I am interested in the set $\{(1-t)^4, 4(1-t)^3 t, 6 (1-t)^2 t^2, 4(1-t) t^3, t^4) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Is the concept of "envelope" useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)